# Arbitrary intersection of open sets is not open in cocountable topology on $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

Give an example to show that arbitrary intersection of open sets is not open in computable topology on $\mathbb R$.

We define $U_x=\mathbb R-\{x\}$ where $x\in \mathbb R- \mathbb Q$.
Then each $U_x$ is open.
Now $\bigcap_{x\in \mathbb R-\mathbb Q}U_x=\mathbb R-(\mathbb R-\mathbb Q)=\mathbb Q$ which is not open. Is this example correct?

Comment: Yes that works fine.

Comment: Also OK: $\{0\} = \bigcap_{x \neq 0} U_x$ is not open. A $T_1$ Alexandroff space is discrete.